# Help on LPCWSTR

Tags: winapi, qt, msdn

How can i convet QString to LPCWSTR...

QString a = QString("\\.\%1:").arg( "G" );

i have to use it for the below function

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile ( a ,0,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // share mode
                     // NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCHAR to LPCWSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164509/wchar-to-lpcwstr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [toWCharArray](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#toWCharArray) function.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://tkrotoff.blogspot.com/2010/04/code-snippets-about-qstring-wchart.html) are some code snippets.